# TableView sizes differently in iPhone5s and 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

My tableview size correctly (the cell filled the whole screen) in iPhone 5s, but not in iPhone 6.

In iPhone 6, the width of the cells does not extend to the end of the row. Please see the picture for details.

**Correct sizing in iPhone 5s**

[image: Correct sizing in iPhone 5s]

**Incorrect sizing in iPhone 6**
[image]

Any suggestion would be appreciated, Thanks.

**Current Setting**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set Width & Height constraints using AutoLayouts..for Tableview as below

```
XCode ---> Editor --> Pin --> Width

XCode ---> Editor --> Pin --> Height
```

If any yellow/red mark is present at view.

```
XCode --> Editor --> Resolve Auto Layout Issues --> Reset to suggested constraints...
```

Then the width & Height is handled for All the devices by AutoLayouts itself..

Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

You need to update autoResizing Or Autolayouts for iPhone 6. If issue still exist update layouts for cells also.

Comment: Autolayouts seems doesn't help, please see my edited question.